# Unable to fire DDL trigger before the dropping the table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that throws the error on dropping the table in the oracle live sql. In my code the trigger is created successfully but on  trying to drop the table the different error i.e., Encountered the symbol "Drop" is shown

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER drop_trigger  
   BEFORE DROP ON SCHEMA
   BEGIN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'Cannot drop the table'); 
   END; 
 
  drop table emp;
```

Error:

```
Errors: TRIGGER DROP_TRIGGER
Line/Col: 5/3 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP"
```

Also tried to replace the line
"BEFORE DROP ON SCHEMA"
with
"BEFORE DROP ON DATABASE"

and new error came i.e.
"ORA-01031: insufficient privileges "

The code is performed on Oracle Live Sql

Comment: The code you have written is fine and should give you the expected outcome. See the same [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=155195b2cea177728426d29703901faf). But I never experienced the Oracle live SQL, so what I can tell is try out a `/` at end of trigger body and see if it works. Otherwise it could be that Oracle live SQL don't allow to drop any object or missing privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but that are just 2 statements. So it is a problem, how statements can run in Oracle Live Sql. Try execute each statement alone.

Your user needs the CREATE TRIGGER system privileg.
Please refer to the oracle documentation.